# Topo correction

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, topography

[image]How can I address the problems associated with the hills shadows in GEE, as shown in the screenshot attached? It brings a lot of complication.

```
AN IMAGE USED
// Filter to 2019 Landsat 8 images over banglore.
var L8 = ee.ImageCollection(‘LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2’).select(‘SR_B[2-7]’)
.filter(ee.Filter.date(‘2022-05-01’, ‘2022-08-31’))
.filterMetadata(“CLOUD_COVER”, “less_than”, 0.5)
.filter(ee.Filter.bounds(ROI))
//.map(maskL8sr)
.median()
.clip(ROI);

// Visualization parameter.
var rgbVis = {min:7557.04, max:13030.96, bands:[‘SR_B4’, ‘SR_B3’, ‘SR_B2’]}
Map.centerObject(ROI, 10);
Map.addLayer(L8, rgbVis, ‘2023’, false)
print(‘Image details: 2023’,L8);[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is no image attached.

Comment: Hi Nokos, the images is attached now. The RF classifier keeps on misclassifiying  the hillshadows as water or wetland. Now I am desperately in for for help to perform the terrain correction.

Comment: The easiest method is to simply add more training data that includes pixels in the shadowed regions.  But if you really want to do terrain correction, there are multiple sources: https://mygeoblog.com/2018/10/17/terrain-correction-in-gee/, https://www.cde.unibe.ch/e65013/e542846/e707304/e707386/e707388/CDE_Pre-processingTool-BackgroundAndMethods_eng.pdf, etc

Comment: @NoelGorelick thank you so much I will try both options.